# Where should a site’s language be set?

Tags: html, seo

I was searching at [w3schools about the meta tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp), but there's nothing about content language.

What is the place where I should set the site’s language?

**Edit:** it should be compatible with HTML 5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The document language should be specified using the [`lang` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/dirlang.html#h-8.1) on the highest element to which it applies — which is usually `html`. e.g.

```
<html lang="en-gb">
```

You can use it to indicate changes in language if needed:

```
<p>She has a certain <span lang="fr">je ne sais quoi</span></p>
```

You can also specify the language(s) of the target audience with a Content-Language HTTP header.

```
Content-Language: en, fr
```

There isn't much point is duplicating that with `<meta http-equiv`, especially if you have a suitable `lang` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/core-attributes/xml-lang

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```